# Remove end of file after matching regex keeping the expression matched in multiple files (sed?)

Tags: regex, bash, date, sed, zsh

I'm cleaning up a lot of markdown files to import them into Pelican (a static website generator). While compiling I get errors about the date format in multiple files. What I need to do is leave the date (yyyy-mm-dd) and delete to the end of the line after it. This is the last try I've made with `sed`and RegEx:

> `sed -i "s/\(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\)\*/\1 /g" *.md`

My hope was that sed would take the whole pattern within the parenthesis as `1` and then keep it as the substitution string.

This is an example of the errors (all numbers change):

> ERROR: Could not process ./2010-12-28-the-open-internet-a-case-for-net-neutrality.html.md
>
> | ValueError: '2010-12-28 21:22:00.000000000 +01:00 true' is not a valid date
>
> ERROR: Could not process ./2011-05-27-two-one-must-read-internet-business-book.html.md
>
> | ValueError: '2011-05-27 13:08:00.000000000 +02:00 true' is not a valid date

I've looked around SO but all I've found is about static strings, while mine change all the time.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: Great refference post, thanks @sundeep

Answer (score 0):

**Please take care of these files, at least make a backup before using sed on them.**

This can be done by using the i flag with an extension: `-i.bckup`.

So I am not sure that You want to modify the content of the files or the names itself.
An expression that would only keep the date would be:

```
sed -r 's/([^-]*[-][^-]*[-][^-]*).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks @ntj. I want to change the content of the file.

Comment: It did not work. It changes other parts of the file(links to images) but not the date.

Comment: `sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/g'` that would be a more strict expression. Note that all chars after date are deleted in every line. Now this expr runs globally.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `sed` is not seeing `\d` as a metacharacter meaning `[0-9]`, so use it instead.

```
sed -i -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/' *.md
```

Note:

# with the `-r` extended regex option you do not escape your pattern groupings `()`

# no need for the `/g` option since you are removing everything after the first match

# `.*` is probably the wildcard you meant to use. `*` matches any number of the preceeding pattern and `.` matches any single character.

Here is a command line test:

```
echo '2011-05-27 13:08:00.000000000 +02:00 true' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/\1/'
```

which outputs:

```
2011-05-27
```

Comment: It changed other lines in the posts but not the one I'm targeting

Comment: I've added a working command line example of the same sed command using the information from your error message. Perhaps you should have included a small example of one of the input files.

Comment: I included the exact string in the original posts as the value errors. I've since expanded with a couple examples.